# NSPathcontrol alternative

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspathcontrol

I am trying to customize an NSPathControl (custom look, menu on items) but after hours passed on it, I cannot achieve what I want.
Do you know an alternative control for representing a path?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Comment: Could you describe the desired functionality?

Comment: Well, 8 years later, I found meanwhile an alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just line up some custom buttons with graphics that look like the path control.

However, you might want to step back and ask if you really need to customize the control. The standard controls are part of the interface grammar and user are comfortable with them and know what to expect. Making them look different implies to the user that they will behave differently. If the behavior is the same I wouldn't mess with customization to much.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a NSPathControl subview which can achieve this.
Feel free to check it out:

[Github](https://github.com/iluuu1994/Pathbar)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this contribution.